# Country name from PHP

Tags: php, ip-address

How to get country name from an IP address using PHP without using a commercial GeoIP Region Edition?

Comment: Without a *commercial* API or with no GeoIP API at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can do it simply using PHP, but I have found a free API solution that you can use.  It requires simple post and response.
http://www.hostip.info/use.html

example post:
http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=12.215.42.19

example response:
Country: UNITED STATES (US)
City: Sugar Grove, IL

Comment: Does it only work in the US? I don't get any valid response with my IP from Germany.

Answer (score 8):

Code

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://freegeoip.appspot.com/json/66.102.13.106');
$expression = json_decode($json);
print_r($expression);
```

Result

```
stdClass Object
(
    [status] => 1
    [ip] => 66.102.13.106
    [countrycode] => US
    [countryname] => United States
    [regioncode] => CA
    [regionname] => California
    [city] => Mountain View
    [zipcode] => 94043
    [latitude] => 37.4192
    [longitude] => -122.057
)
```

To get countryname

```
echo $expression->countryname;
```

Result

```
United States
```

Comment: Assuming you have `json_decode()` which ships only from PHP >= 5.2.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [free IP geolocation webservice](http://freegeoip.appspot.com/)