# php: api to get location from user-ip

Tags: php, api, geolocation, location, ip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Country name from php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998386/country-name-from-php)

is there an open database/api (=don't want to install anything on my mysqldb) to get the location from a user by his ip per php/api-query?

edit:
i found: http://ipinfodb.com/index.php
are there any good alternatives?

Comment: Duplicate of [many many questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+geolocation+ip). Please search before asking.