# How do I serve a different HTML page depending on user's country?

Tags: html, apache, ip-geolocation

I'm using Apache 2 and currently static HTML pages.

I want my Euro-zone visitors to see a page that has the price in euros. My UK visitors should see a page that the price in GBP. Everyone I want to see the price in dollars.

I realise this might be a question more suited for https://superuser.com/ - but I don't know whether the solution is Apache 2 configuration or whether I need to use code.

Edit: I'm willing to try any client-side or server-side application. I don't need to convert the currencies - it is a fixed euro price, and fixed GBP price, and a fixed dollar price.

Comment: In ASP.NET I do something similar for our online shops. I use a geo location database, i.e. mapping IP addresses to country codes. I guess that this is not easily to solve with pure web server configuration.

Comment: What about using something like this: http://kabo.nu/currency_widget/ or this: http://www.techmug.com/ajax-currency-converter-with-google-api/ to convert currency on the fly? Only drawback, your users needs to have javascript on for this to work..

Comment: @UweKeim I guess problem is he's serving static html page, with no server-side application that could do the conversions.. am I right?

Comment: @redShadow Yes, I guess you're right.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use mod_rewrite for that:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^192\.168\.1\.[0-9]+$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^192\.168\.3\.[0-9]+$
RewriteCond %{PATH_INFO} =/

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/abc_euro.htm$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^192\.168\.2\.[0-9]+$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^192\.168\.4\.[0-9]+$
RewriteCond %{PATH_INFO} =/

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/abc_uk.htm$1 [R=301,L]
```

(Assuming that `192.168.1.*` and `192.168.3.*` ip ranges are from eu, while `192.168.2.*` and `192.168.4.*` are from the Uk)

I'm not very sure about usage of `RewriteCond %{PATH_INFO} =/` to indicate "request to root path" and thus avoid infinite redirect-loops.. maybe it can be done better using `LocationMatch` or so..?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

- [Country name from php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998386/country-name-from-php)

or this:

- http://teamtutorials.com/web-development-tutorials/how-to-get-a-users-geo-location#.TvXQ-dRSR2A

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript something along the lines of:

- get the ip - http://www.hashemian.com/tools/visitor-IP.htm
- work out where it is - http://www.hackingspirits.com/cyb_forensic/fsic_articles/loc_place.html
- convert the currency or show/hide as appropriate

*p.s redShadow's answer is better :-)*