# How to add a user location in PHP?

Tags: php, location

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Country name from php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998386/country-name-from-php)

I am managing user data in PHP for the admin side. I want to ask a question: how can I add the location from which the user gets registered and then display that location on the admin side?

Comment: provide a field named location best would be select dropdown with all the countries and make it compulsory to be filled . Once location selected store that information in user table and then display it by taking it from users table

Comment: but Umair iqbal the real problem  i am facing is that i can not detect the location of the user how can i  detect that location?

Comment: at the registration time you can ask the user to provide his location. or ask him to provide his time zone from which you can get his location. lastly if you want to get automatically get the ip of the user once he is login

Comment: i used the $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]; to get ip but i cant convert the ip into city or country name and i don't want to bother user by asking tooo many questions

Comment: unfortunately desktops n laptops don't have GPS

Comment: I think he talk about Network Auto-Location like Google.com...